# How to add a header ExpandProperty in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build a script to help me figure out service accounts using Kerberos Constrained Delegation. Two of the properties that I am interested in are multi-valued, so I am using the -ExpandProperty switch. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out a 'clean' way to output the property name with the expanded values. Because the two expanded properties have similar values and can overlap, I ***need*** to do something to show where ServicePrincipalNames ends and msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo begins. The code below works, but it seems like there should be a way of getting the same (or very similar) output without having to use Write-Output.

```
$Account = "svcSomeService"

# Query AD once
$Details = Get-ADUser -Identity $Account -Properties *

# Main result set
$Details | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, DisplayName, Enabled, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, LockedOut, AccountNotDelegated, TrustedForDelegation, TrustedToAuthForDelegation, KerberosEncryptionType

# Expand muulti-value column ServicePrincipalNames
Write-Output "ServicePrincipalNames"
Write-Output "---------------------"
$Details | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServicePrincipalNames    #Tried with and without Format-Table

# Expand muulti-value column msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo
Write-Output "`n"
Write-Output "msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo"
Write-Output "------------------------"
$Details | Select-Object -ExpandProperty msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo #Tried with and without Format-Table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a `[pscustomobject]` that houses the expanded values in distinct properties:

```
[pscustomobject] @{
  ServicePrincipalNames = $Details.ServicePrincipalNames
  msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo = $Details.msDS-AllowedToDelegateTo
}
```

Note:

- `$Details.ServicePrincipalNames` is a more efficient alternative to 
  `$Details | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServicePrincipalNames`, via the [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) feature.
- As for display formatting on the *caller*'s side: Since the output object has only *two* properties, it will implicitly render as a *table* (implicit [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)), which doesn't provide much space for showing the individual values. Piping to [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) helps, but additionally requires you to raise [`$FormatEnumerationLimit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#formatenumerationlimit) to avoid truncation;<sup>[1]</sup> to provide a simple example:

  ```
   $FormatEnumerationLimit=100 # !! As of v7.2.2: only effective in *global* scope
   [pscustomobject] @{ prop1 = 1..100; prop2 = 80..1 } | Format-List
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Due to an unfortunate bug up to at least PowerShell 7.2.2, setting this preference variable is only effective in the *global* scope - see [GitHub issue #888](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/888).</sup>